# Syntax Backbone model.save

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am having problems figuring out the model.save syntax in Backbone + Coffeescript. (Rails 3)

I have the following:

```
@options.product_search.save({'url'  : $("#product_search").val()},
  {success: (event) => alert "StackOverflow"},
  {error:  (response) => alert "oh no!"}
  )
```

1. The success-event works in this case, the error-event doesn't.
2. I also can't figure out how to add multiple actions to a success-event as coffeescript gives me a syntax-error when I split the code into multiple lines inside the success event.

Thank you for your help!
Best, Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting in a third parameter into the save method, where it only takes two:

```
model.save([attributes], [options])
```

This is just a coffeescript/javascript syntax error that's easy to fix.

Try this:

```
@options.product_search.save
  url: $("#product_search").val()
,
  success: (model, response) ->
    alert "StackOverflow"
    alert "More alerts"

  error: (model, response) ->
    alert "oh no!"
```

Comment: must have skipped the syntax in the backbone docs! thank you very much @joshvermaire, works like a charm!